# How to test that functions within useEffect are called?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-hooks, karma-runner, enzyme

I have a useEffect function within my component that calls rtwo functions passed into the component like so:

COMPONENT:

```
const FetcherComponent = ({ controller = {}, ...props }) => {
  const { submitData, checkData } = controller;
  const { poll } = props;

  useEffect(() => {
    const init = async () => {
      if (poll) {
        const resp = await submitData();

        if (resp.failed) {
          return;
        }
      }
      await checkData(poll);
    };

    init();
  }, [poll, submitData, checkData]);

  return (
    <Spinner />
  );
};
```

The functions come from a hook that I created.

HOOK:

```
function useFetcher(props = {}) {
  const handleSubmitData = useCallback(
    useErrorHandler(() => () => {}, callback),
    []
  );

  const handleStatusCheck = useCallback(
    useErrorHandler((isPolling = false) => () => {}, callback),
    []
  );

  const handleSuccessResponse = useCallback(
    ({ data, showStatusPage = false }) => {},
    [deps]
  );

  const handleErrorResponse = useCallback((error) => {}, [deps]);

  const submitData = useCallback(async () => {
    const submission = await handleSubmitData();
    // ...
    // ...
  }, [deps]);

  const checkData = useCallback(
    async (isPolling) => {
      const statusCheck = await handleStatusCheck(isPolling);
      // ...
      // ...
    },
    [deps]
  );

  return {
    submitData,
    checkData,
  };
}
```

This is an example of how this is currently used.

INTEGRATION:

```
const ExampleComponent = ({ props }) => {
  const statusChecker = useFetcher();

  return <StatusChecker controller={statusChecker} isPolling />;
};
```

How can I assert that the two functions `submitData` and `checkData`, are called when the poll prop value is true?

I have tried multiple ways, but nothing seems to work. My application is using Karma with Enzyme.

Comment: Where do `submitData` and `checkData` functions come from?

Comment: Passed in as props currently. Trying to keep all the business logic in a container file.

Comment: Please give a minimal, complete example. When does `poll` value become true?

Comment: Thanks. Post updated with a more complete example of the setup.

Comment: Can yo post what you have tried so far as well? e.g your test case code